# How to request from JAVA to support something?

Tags: java, localization, refactoring, jira, jira-plugin

[**Atlassian JIRA**](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) is a powerfull issue tracker which I am using it for a long time, as it is a good issue trakcer I bound to Localize it to my locale.

I found Their page in [Linkedin](http://www.linkedin.com/groups?mostPopular=&gid=117832) and [asked them if I can translate it](http://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=117832&type=member&item=37468151&qid=b6a58738-89af-45fa-9993-5750f68ad781), as it was welcomed in the community I started translating, I'd post first part of my translation for them and after a while they [told me here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/TRANS-111) that

> Java does not support fa_IR locale.

and

> - try to force java to support fa_IR
> - refactor TAC so having locale is

What can I do to get JAVA attention to support fa_IR locale or something else to help JIRA supporting it? Actually I didn't get the minning of `refactor TAC so having locale is` how can I deal with it?

Comment: **Update :** I don't see Persian locale as supported by jdk but do see the encoding for it
supported by jdk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Sun/Oracle Java implementation is based on OpenJDK (or rather, they've released the initial official implementation under GPL, as OpenJDK) and the two projects are closely linked.

You can check the contributor guidelines here: http://openjdk.java.net/contribute/ (which includes a link to http://bugs.sun.com/)

**Update :** Here is the page you can find the guidline to add another locale to JAVA
http://openjdk.java.net/groups/i18n/  look for **Include locale in JRE** in that page

Comment: as you answer was very close to what I was looking for, I updated your answer with correct link in the site you mentioned and Marked your answer as the correct one. Thank you man.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [the original text](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/TRANS-111?focusedCommentId=223714&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-223714)

> Alternatively, if the locale is
>   correct we will have to postpone the
>   implementation. There are two
>   solutions we can explore, but neither
>   in the short term:
>
> - try to force java to support fa_IR
> - refactor TAC so having locale is optional

Neither of these is anything you can fix. The first means Sun / Oracle will have to ship an additional Locale with their JRE, the second means Atlassian will have to rewrite their code to not use Locales. Neither of these are things you can do anything about.

Comment: I know that these are not things that I can fix, I meant that `how can I **ask* JAVA to add this locale to their supporting locals. I think that you didn't get my point for the main reason, but for the second One I appriciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't force Oracle to support "fa_IR".  You can ask them.  You can offer them large amounts of money to do it.  But that's about the limit of your leverage.

Somehow, I don't think that attempting to put moral pressure on Oracle is going to work.  They are a commercial organization whose primary responsibility is to make money for their share-holders.

---

You could consider implementing the locale yourself by modifying and building your own version of OpenJDK 6 / 7.  Indeed, you could then contribute this back to the OpenJDK project so that other people will benefit from it in some future release.  (Probably not until OpenJDK 8 now ...)

Answer (score 1):

You can provision your own Java locales through the SPI - [here's an example](http://klaus.e175.net/java-locale-sh).

When it comes to I18N-enabling software, you'll have to make a decision about how far you want to go - currencies, calendars, time zones, UI layout, etc. Swapping strings is the easy bit.

Comment: It was really a nice link. and also your answer was quiet good, I really enjoyed it.